# Algolia and firestore prices + reviews

Tags: android, firebase, search, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I wanna make sure I get the pricing model correct.

I use Algolia to search in my apps, so I need a user index for Firestore 
Take an example and say that I have 10000 users.
**2 methods are presented to me:**
-- Either I do an indexing say every 5 minutes.
-- Either I index every time a document is changed in Firestore

I think that the first method would be impossible because of the operating limit of firestore (that would be about 2,800,000 reading) but I'm not sure.
For the second, I hesitate.

How can I solve this?

Comment: And I have to ask. If 2 documents are modified at the same time what would happen? And can we search with Algolia during indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to Algolia, you are charged by plan which includes your permitted limits for records count and indexing operations.  A good article is "[How Algolia counts records and operations](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/accounts-billing/how-algolia-count-records-and-operation/)".  In your described situation, you appear to have frequent updates so will need to multiply that out and make sure your plan handles that many indexing operations.  The "Essential" plan is pay-as-you-go for flexibility. Read more about pricing [here](https://www.algolia.com/pricing).

> If 2 documents are modified at the same time what would happen?

If 2 documents are modified at the same time, this is 2 operations in Algolia (x1 for each record update).

> And can we search with Algolia during indexing?

Yes, you can search while indexing. All write operations (e.g., add, update, delete indexing operations) are asynchronous. Your request to add/update/delete is added to a task queue and processed in order.  You can continue to search your existing index, but you will not see the updated information until the task is published.